# EmbeddedWB & jQuery

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

How can I inject jQuery and execute a function inside an EmbeddedWB control and get it's result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the IHtmlDocument2 interface of the document loaded into the browser to get at and manipulate its DOM.

See http://www.delphidabbler.com/articles?article=21, which includes how to get a return value from the script.

Comment: What about `TEmbeddedWB.ExecScriptEx` method ?

Comment: "What about TEmbeddedWB.ExecScriptEx?"  Sure but maybe the old canard about the hungry man and fish versus fishing line is relevant.